# How to return in the last tabs in javascript (Angular Material) with a button?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, material-design

**My code summary**

I want if I click on "go back content", I return at the content tabs 1;

```html
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs>
    <mat-tab label="content 1">
        ........
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="content 2">
        <button mat-raised-button (click)=""> go Back content 1</button>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: You should use a function with your click event where you set the value of a variable called `selected` to 0. `<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selected">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs [(selectedIndex)]="selectedTab">
    <mat-tab label="content 1">
       <p>one</p>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="content 2">
       <p>two</p>
       <button mat-raised-button (click)="openContentOne()"> go Back content 1</button>
   </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

and in your ts:

```
selectedTab = 0;
openContentOne() {
    this.selectedTab = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the current selected tab's index to a variable and then set that variable when needed, like this:

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex">
    <mat-tab label="content 1">
        ........
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="content 2">
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="selectedIndex = 0"> go Back content 1</button>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

You can read more [here](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview).